# Unexpected SUM result found using SUM with JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables 'tbl_orders' and 'tbl_instore'. tbl_orders have 'sel_product_qty' which I want to date wise SUM and table(tbl_instore) have 'inst_prod_qty' and 'chln_amount' which I calculate and want to get purchased unit price. But when I use join query on those two tables, the `SUM(sel_product_qty)` produces double, triple and quadruple amount from the expected result.

Sample data tables are..

Table "tbl_order":

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
| order_id | ord_det_id | product_id | sel_product_qty | selling_price |   order_date_time  |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
|  3       |     1      |      4     |       50        |     67.82     | 2019-03-21 21:52:21|
|  4       |     1      |      1     |       100       |     37.88     | 2019-03-21 21:52:21|
|  5       |     2      |      4     |       120       |     67.82     | 2018-03-23 00:02:36|
|  6       |     3      |      3     |       300       |     123.67    | 2019-03-23 00:04:38|
|  7       |     3      |      2     |       50        |     76.28     | 2019-03-23 00:04:38|
|  8       |     4      |      4     |       50        |     67.82     | 2019-03-24 12:13:06|
|  9       |     4      |      2     |       100       |     76.28     | 2019-03-24 12:13:06|
|  10      |     5      |      1     |       10        |     37.88     | 2019-03-25 12:56:40|
|  11      |     5      |      4     |       7         |     67.82     | 2019-03-25 12:56:40|
|  12      |     6      |      4     |       23        |     67.82     | 2019-03-29 00:29:14|
|  13      |     6      |      2     |       25        |     76.28     | 2019-03-29 00:29:14|
|  16      |     7      |      1     |       120       |     37.88     | 2019-04-14 16:51:10|
|  17      |     7      |      3     |       90        |     123.67    | 2019-04-14 16:51:11|
|  18      |     8      |      1     |       100       |     66.95     | 2019-04-22 23:30:39|
|  19      |     8      |      2     |       22        |     70.04     | 2019-04-22 23:30:39|
+----------+------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Table "tbl_instore":

```
+----------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+
| in_st_id | s_inv_id | product_id | inst_prod_qty | chln_amount |  instore_date_time |
+----------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+
|    1     |    1     |     1      |    1000       |    65852    |  2/14/2018 17:28   |
|    14    |    9     |     1      |    100        |    6400     |  4/26/2019 8:26    |
|    3     |    2     |     1      |    2000       |    58885    |  3/19/2019 17:32   |
|    5     |    3     |     1      |    100        |    3588     |  3/19/2019 17:35   |
|    11    |    7     |     1      |    1000       |    65000    |  4/22/2019 23:17   |
|    9     |    5     |     1      |    100        |    6345     |  4/20/2019 0:13    |
|    12    |    8     |     2      |    100        |    7800     |  4/22/2019 23:20   |
|    8     |    4     |     2      |    2000       |    144567   |  3/23/2019 0:04    |
|    7     |    4     |     3      |    1000       |    121665   |  3/23/2019 0:04    |
|    13    |    8     |     3      |    150        |    32000    |  4/22/2019 23:20   |
|    15    |    9     |     3      |    100        |    19000    |  4/26/2019 8:26    |
|    10    |    6     |     4      |    1000       |    88022    |  4/20/2019 0:16    |
|    6     |    3     |     4      |    100        |    6582     |  3/19/2019 17:35   |
|    4     |    2     |     4      |    1000       |    65882    |  3/19/2019 17:32   |
|    2     |    1     |     4      |    5000       |    359877   |  2/14/2018 17:28   |
+----------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

The following query I have currently tried:

```
SELECT SUM(tbl_orders.sel_product_qty) AS `sel_prod_qty`,
(SUM(chln_amount) / SUM(inst_prod_qty)) AS `pur_uni_price`, 
            date_format(`order_date_time`, '%M-%Y') as `month`, 
            tbl_orders.product_id AS `product_id`
            FROM tbl_orders
            INNER JOIN tbl_instore ON tbl_instore.product_id = tbl_orders.product_id
            WHERE YEAR(`order_date_time`)= '2019' 
            GROUP BY `month`, `product_id`;
```

Which return the following result:

```
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
| sel_prod_qty | pur_uni_price | month  | product_id |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     1320     |    47.923256  | Apr-19 |     1      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     44       |    72.555714  | Apr-19 |     2      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     270      |    138.132    | Apr-19 |     3      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     660      |    47.923256  | Mar-19 |     1      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     350      |    72.555714  | Mar-19 |     2      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     900      |    138.132    | Mar-19 |     3      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     520      |    73.290563  | Mar-19 |     4      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
```

If I run the query individually without `JOIN`, I will get `SUM(sel_prod_qty)` value as following (also my expected result should be):

```
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
| sel_prod_qty | pur_uni_price | month  | product_id |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     220      |    47.923256  | Apr-19 |     1      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     22       |    72.555714  | Apr-19 |     2      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     90       |    138.132    | Apr-19 |     3      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     110      |    47.923256  | Mar-19 |     1      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     175      |    72.555714  | Mar-19 |     2      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     300      |    138.132    | Mar-19 |     3      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
|     130      |    73.290563  | Mar-19 |     4      |
+--------------+---------------+--------+------------+
```

So, my question is, why does my query return `SUM(sel_product_qty)` double, triple and quadruple amount from the expected result?

Comment: What was surprising about the result?

Comment: 'surprising result.' doesn't tell us anything about expected result. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/  with sample data and expected result would help

Comment: I’m guessing that inst_prod_qty is the quantity of product currently in store - if so, then what on earth is ‘chnl_amount’ ?  If you want the purchase price for an order, then that should be stored on the order line - specifically NEVER use the current in-store price, since that can change at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `sel_prod_qty`,
       `pur_uni_price`, 
       `month`, 
        orders.product_id AS `product_id`
     FROM  
        (SELECT product_id,SUM(sel_product_qty) AS `sel_prod_qty`,
                DATE_FORMAT(`order_date_time`, '%M-%Y') AS `month` 
           FROM tbl_orders 
          WHERE YEAR(`order_date_time`)='2019' 
         GROUP BY `month`, `product_id`) orders
     INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT product_id,(SUM(chln_amount) / SUM(inst_prod_qty)) AS `pur_uni_price` 
            FROM tbl_instore GROUP BY product_id) instore 
              ON orders.product_id=instore.product_id;
```

I created two sub-query from those tables that you joined because what doesn't work is that you are doing `INNER JOIN ... ON tbl_instore.product_id = tbl_orders.product_id`. Which if you refer back to your table, those value were repeated multiple times in both tables. Therefore, this sub-queries  will perform the mathematical operation and the outer query will only return the results from it.

Answer (score 0):

The pur_uni_price field is not an aggregate field anymore, therefore you need to add it on your GROUP BY. See code below

```
SELECT SUM(tbl_orders.sel_product_qty) AS `sel_prod_qty`,
    (SUM(chln_amount) / SUM(inst_prod_qty)) AS `pur_uni_price`, 
    date_format(`order_date_time`, '%M-%Y') as `month`, 
    tbl_orders.product_id AS `product_id`
    FROM tbl_orders
    INNER JOIN tbl_instore ON tbl_instore.product_id = tbl_orders.product_id
    WHERE YEAR(`order_date_time`)= '2019' 
    GROUP BY `month`, `product_id`, (SUM(chln_amount) / SUM(inst_prod_qty))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But it's give an error like "Invalid use of group function"